# List loop operations with linq

Tags: c#, linq, list, loops

I've list like this:

```
var query = Enumerable.Range(0, drea2.count / 4 * 1440).Select((n, index) =>
{
    if ((index >= 480 && index < 750) || (index >= 810 && index < 1080))
        return 0;
    else if (index >= 750 && index < 810)
        return 1;
    else
        return 2;
});
```

But, this range must be changeable. For Example;
I've also a list contains these indexes. These indexes may be different from each other.

[image]

1440 means 1440 min. of a day. I want to add 1440 to these indexes. For example:

query[0], ... query[479] = 2 --- query [1440], ... query[1919] = 2 --- query[2880] = 2

query[480], .. query[749] = 0, --- query[810], .. query[1079] = 0, --- query[1920], .. query[2189] = 0..

So, whatever count of drea2 list, the query has size that (drea2.count / 4 * 1440)

How can I do this?

EDIT: If drea2.Count() returns 6, my if condition must have 6 different phrase per 1440 index. For first if: (And query Range must has 7200 size, now)

```
if ((index >= 480 && index < 750) || (index >= 810 && index < 1080))
    return 0; // for 1

if ((index >= 480 + 1440 && index < 750 + 1440) || (index >= 810 + 1440 && index < 1080 + 1440))
        return 0; // for 2
...               // for 3 (+ 2880)
...               // for 4 (+ 4320)
...               // for 5 (+ 5760)

if ((index >= 480 + 7200 && index < 750 + 7200) || (index >= 810 + 7200 && index < 1080 + 7200))
```

Comment: What do you mean by changeable? What does `query` output that does not satisfy you?

Comment: query list range depends on drea2.Count() value. However, I don't drea2 count at runtime.

Comment: Do you want the sub-ranges to be applied to the first range of `1440` items, or do you want it to be applied __per__ `1440` items? I mean from `1440` to `2880` you'd have the same checks but this time 480+1440, `810+1440` ... and etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the updates by the OP, I have rewritten my answer. For reference of the previous version, follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/23058949/3).

Here is the proposed solution, assuming the `drea2` collection is an array, or list (thus implementing the `IList<int>` interface) and each `4` items in this list form the ranges to be used in the produced sequences of `1440` items:

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetQuery(IList<int> drea2)
{
    var count = drea2.Count;
    var result = new int[(count/4)*1440];

    for (var i = 0, fillIndexStart = 0; i < count; i+= 4, fillIndexStart += 1440) {
        var rangeIndices = new[] { 
            drea2[i], 
            drea2[i+1], 
            drea2[i+2], 
            drea2[i+3] 
        };

        for (var j = 0; j < rangeIndices[0]; j++) {
            result[fillIndexStart + j] = 2;                 
        }
        for (var j = rangeIndices[3]; j < 1440; j++) {
            result[fillIndexStart + j] = 1;                 
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Unfortunately, there is no `Linq` here, but I hope it does what is needed.

The previous code would have used this condition, instead of the two for loops in the method above:

```
if ((j >= rangeIndices[0] && j < rangeIndices[1]) 
        || (j >= rangeIndices[2] && j < rangeIndices[3]))
    result[fillIndexStart + j] = 0;
else if (j >= rangeIndices[1] && j < rangeIndices[2])
    result[fillIndexStart + j] = 1;
else
    result[fillIndexStart + j] = 2;
```

Since an array is always filled with the default values, we can take advantage of `result` being full of zeros. That is why I have rewritten the conditions as 2 `for` loops

**Note**. The code above relies on `drea2.Count / 4` to be `0`. Otherwise, you will get `IndexOutOfRangeException` when initializing the `rangeIndices` array.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm preparing an EDIT. Please read this edit.

Comment: @team16sah, please check the updated answer. I added `workingIndex`, which is based on the real index and will convert the list to section of 1440 items each. Each section will have items according to your sub-range checks. I hope this is what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks a lot. In addition, is it possible to take these indexes from drea2 list. As shown, these indexes are contained by drea2 list: 480, 750, 810, 1080.. Most important point is; These values may be irregular. So, they may not repeat..

Comment: @team16sah, it is possible, but you need to provide with the connection between the `drea2` values and what you need to do. In other words, how should we interpret the contents of `drea2`?

Comment: For one 1440, the phrase is;

if ((index >= drea2[0] && index < drea2[1]) || (index >= drea2[2] && index < drea2[3]))

return 0;

Comment: Do you mean each `4` indices of the `drea2` list correspond to a chunk of `1440` values? Is that why you use the `drea2.Count/4` ?

Comment: This gives me days count. (24 / 4 = 6) and now I have 6 days and 1440 minutes for each days. I have to fill these minutes with various digits

Comment: @team16sah, see my _entirely updated_ answer. Alas, no `Linq` in it

Comment: Thanks for your update. I have no chance to try it for now. But I have a question for this : Is there a performance diversity between this one and a linq solution?

Comment: @team16sah, I did some update, this is now the latest suggestion. Performance difference exists, but it is small, even for ranges like yours. Usually, the `for` loop is better, if you compile with optimization flags enabled. Also the `Linq` solution in the above case would require you to call `ToArray()` or `ToList()` which would IMHO reduce the performance. If you don't call these, the result will evaluate could evaluate the query more than once.

Comment: I take an error (IndexOutOfRangeException )from above code. drea2 size is 24 and count is 4. Where is the problem?

Comment: @team16sah, I did a mistake with the `fillIndexStart` usage, it is the one performing the out-of-range exception. Now it should work

Comment: Where the if condition should be in code? Where I replace them? @ivaylo

Comment: @team16sah, I have replaced them in my answer. I added them below so you are not wondering where did your if-else logic go. I just transformed it to two for loops. Just use the `GetQuery` method - its enough

Answer (score 1):

If the 480-750-810-1080-1440 sequence is completely hardcoded, and you just need to loop as many times as you have days, you can just do a modulo 1400 operation at the start of the block:

```
var query = Enumerable.Range(0, drea2.count / 4 * 1440).Select((n, i) =>
{
    var index = i % 1440;
    if ((index >= 480 && index < 750) || (index >= 810 && index < 1080))
        return 0;
    else if (index >= 750 && index < 810)
        return 1;
    else
        return 2;
});
```